# Git revert- reverted to previous commit, but master is now broken

Tags: git, git-revert

I made some changes to the `master` branch on the server yesterday, and today a colleague mentioned that doing this had broken another part of the website (it's been written in Django/ Python).

I decided to revert my changes to a previous commit, on which I knew that this feature was still working. To do this I connected to the server, and ran the following commands:

> git log
>
> git revert f5729c62bbef52bdaf7c106465910cb618a26814

(The last working commit)

However, when I now view the website, I am getting an `Internal Server Error`, which I was previously not getting... The thing is, I know that this commit that I have just reverted to was working correctly... and I now cannot fix this `server error`... anyone have any ideas how I can resolve this?

I have tried reverting to a number of different commits- but always seem to get this error...

I also restarted the server after running `revert`, and have tried restoring a number of previous commits and restarting, but none of them seem to work...

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server after you did this? --- (I feel like I should add that, IMO, executing git commands directly on your server isn't the best of practices. You should have a local instance of your web server that you can test changes on)

Comment: Yes, I have tried restarting the server

Comment: To debug a server side error, go check the logs of your webserver (apache ? nginx ?) and your application.

Comment: For the git side of things : please explain how your code is deployed on your production server.

Comment: Are you sure no migrations have been executed? From a Django perspective these migrations won't be reverted unless you manually revert them.

Comment: Do you mean had I run migrations prior to the version on the server breaking, but after my last working commit? Yes I think I probably had... Do I need to run migrations again now, having reverted to a previous commit?